# Trying to do an auto complete in rails I keep getting an active record oci error

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oci8, jquery-rails

What I am trying to do is basically have an auto complete for a text box... the js is working properly but, I keep running into this same error with active record and oracle ruby-oci8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (OCIError: ORA-00904: "'SNOWJ'": invalid ide ntifier: SELECT "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE ( emp_id like "'SNOWJ'" )):
app/controllers/user_controller.rb:7:in `emp_id_autocomplete'
```

This is my Visual model

```
class Visual < ActiveRecord::Base


establish_connection :vtest

self.table_name = 'employee'

belongs_to :user

scope :search_id, lambda {|id|
  where(%q{ emp_id like "?" }, id) 
}

end
```

This is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :emp_id,
```

This is my user controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController


  def emp_id_autocomplete
    @query = params[:term]
    @json = Visual.search_id(@query).collect {|e| e.id}.uniq
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  { render :json => @json.to_json, :layout => false }
    end
  end
end
```

This is my view

```
   <div class='row form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
      <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my routes .

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

# Routes for devise user authentication
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }

 root to: 'entry#index'

 resources :entry do
 end

 resources :user do
   collection do
     get :emp_id_autocomplete
   end
 end
```

This is my app.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require best_in_place
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require moment.js
//= require fullcalendar
//= require daterangepicker.js
//= require entry
//= require user


 $(function() {
                $("#emp_id").autocomplete({
                  source: "user/emp_id_autocomplete",
                  minLength: 3
                });
 });
```

These are my tables   User table has emp_id and Visual model is acutually called employee table and has id. what I want the auto complete to do is looks at the emp_id text box then looks in employee table for an id that matches or is close to matching if possible...

User model table

```
  create_table "users"
    t.string   "emp_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Visual model table

```
 create_table "employee"
   t.string   "id"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in quotes, try to replace:

```
where(%q{ emp_id like "?" }, id)
```

with

```
where("emp_id like ?", id)
```

Comment: I tried where("emp_id like '?'", id)   and got this error now-------ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (OCIError: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis: SELECT "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE (emp_id like ''SNOWJ'')):
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:7:in `emp_id_autocomplete'
@Rustam A. Gasanov

Comment: @user3910236, I see, updated answer, try just ? without any quotes

Comment: I tried the updated answer and got this now.. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (OCIError: ORA-00904: "EMP_ID": invalid identifier: SELECT "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE (emp_id like 'SNOWJ')):  @Rustam A. Gasanov
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:7:in `emp_id_autocomplete'

Comment: @user3910236 now the error tells you that you don't have `emp_id` in `employee` table. You have this field in `users` table, so this is an issue with your logic, not with an sql

Comment: @ Rustam A. Gasanov Ok I changed it to id now... I get this error ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'H'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Visual.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.):
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:7:in `emp_id_autocomplete'

Comment: I figured it out!!!!!!!! all I had to do was add   Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type' and it worked thank you @Rustam A. Gasanov

Comment: I figured it out!!!!!!!! all I had to do was add Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type' and it worked thank you  @ Paweł Dawczak